# Evaluate this triple integral (volume)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> I need to calculate this volume of
>   $$D=\{x^2+y^2-2y\le 0,0\le z\le 10-3\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \}.$$

**My attempt.** So the first one is a shifted cylinder $x^2+(y-1)^2\le 1$ , and the second one is an upside-down cone with vertex $z=10$.

By using cylindrical coordinates I get:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2\sin{\theta}}}\int_{0}^{10-3r}rdzdrd\theta$$

Is this the correct way to approach a shifted region? $x^2+y^2=2y$ implies $r^2=2\sin{\theta}$.

I think I got the integral wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct. The angle $\theta$ should be in the interval $[0,\pi]$, so $0\leq r\leq 2\sin\theta\geq 0$ (note that $r^2\leq 2r\sin\theta$). Thus your triple integral should be
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin{\theta}}\int_{0}^{10-3r}rdzdrd\theta.$$
So what is the final result?

Comment: Could you explain why It is from 0 to $\pi$?

Comment: Draw your circle: it is centered in $(0,1)$ with radius $1$. It is completely contained in the upper half-plane and therefore the angle $\theta$ varies in $[0,\pi]$ (the ray starts in the origin in cylindrical coordinates).

Comment: Thanks, you are magic!

Comment: @NPLS Fine! Let me know if you obtain the correct result.

Comment: yup $10\pi -32/3$

Comment: Yes, I got the same result.

Comment: Can I ask you a little question, so I can refine this technique :) . if I have this region $D=\{x^2+6x+z^2\le0,-1\le y\le0\}$ , is it correct to integrate the volume like that : $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{-6cos\theta}\int_{-1}^{0}rdydrd\theta$

Comment: I think it is $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{0}^{-6cos\theta}\int_{-1}^{0}rdydrd\theta$ otherwise $-6cos\theta$ could be negative.

Comment: I drew a circle onto the z-y plane (2D). and I can see that the circle is in the right side, that why I set $-\pi/2 to \pi/2$ . where did you get that $3\pi/2$ ?

Comment: oh wait I just realised! that the center is at x=-3

Comment: yeah I got consused with the axes

Comment: @NPLS Yes, that's it!